# IconPath not exsist

Tags: c#, naudio

When I'm searching for a IsSystemSoundsSession I can't find the IconPath provided. On my system (Windows 10 1909). I'm getting IconPath `@%SystemRoot%\\System32\\AudioSrv.Dll,-203` This file doesn't exist. (yes I expanded the variable for this, but that resolves to `@C:\Windows\System32\AudioSrv.dll` (notice the '@').

Found a solution. The file that I'm searching for is located in `C:\Windows\System32\AudioSrv.dll`. Notice how there is an `@` part as first character? It looks like that is the problem. Not sure if this is a problem with NAudio or Windows API.

[image: IconPath System Sound]

Code to retrieve the IconPath

```
            MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
            var devices = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active);

            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                var sessions = device.AudioSessionManager.Sessions;
                
                for (int i = 0; i < sessions.Count; i++)
                {
                    var session = sessions[i];
                    var iconPath = session.IconPath;
                    // iconPath == '@%SystemRoot%\\System32\\AudioSrv.Dll,-203'
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hardcode c:\windows\system32 instead, but actually you don't really know that  location. That is where the **environment variable %systemroot%** comes in.

Your @ string is a path name containing this environment variable. You cannot open it as a file, first the variable need be resolved, consider:

```
 string trueIconPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables( iconPath.Substring(1))
```

The outcome will probably be: c:\windows\system32\AudioSrv.dll as intended for your machine.. on my PC it would become f:\cfg1\Windows\System32\AudioSrv.dll

Refer for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I know that I can expand the Variable, and remove the 1ste character. But when I ask the Speaker IconPath I get a valid Path. It looks like that '@' character has a special meaning, but can't find that anywhere what it is. I will edit my answer to clarify that I know of the expanded enviormentvariables :)

Comment: I have no idea why the @ is there P-Storm, suppose the filename is marked because it contains environment variable(s) ? Your complaint was the filename as given did not open properly. I have answered your question, because you suggest in your opening, that hardcoding c:\windows\system32 is a solution. It is not. Please dont change your question on the fly.. use the Edit option only to change the opening text for clarification, or to denote information from answers given. Like my answer.